# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on Android version lower than Lollipop

Tags: android, android-studio, noclassdeffounderror

I have a Nexus 5 device with Android 21 on it. I am testing my project on it with no problem. However, if I test on an Emulator with Google APIs 19 it shows the error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. How could this error occur if it is running well on Lollipop? I even asked my friend with a Sony 4.4 device and it also crashes on his phone. I have my Compile SDK version to 21 and Build Tools set to 21.1.2. I tried gradle clean and I am working on Android Studio. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**This error occurs only on devices that are lower than Lollipop:**

This is what appears in Logcat:

```
02-10 07:46:19.200    2238-2238/com.myproject.android.indonesia E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myproject.android.indonesia, PID: 2238
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.myproject.android.indonesia.task.GetProjectTask$1
            at com.myproject.android.indonesia.task.GetProjectTask.execute(GetProjectTask.java:27)
            at com.myproject.android.indonesia.activity.SplashActivity.launchProjectTask(SplashActivity.java:111)
            at com.myproject.android.indonesia.activity.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:71)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the snippet that calls the getProjectTask()

```
GetProjectTask mGetProjectTask = new GetProjectTask(this);
mGetProjectTask.mUrl.append(Constants.Link.HOST).append(Constants.Webservice.GET_PROJECT);
mGetProjectTask.params.put(Constants.Key.PRJ_LICENCE, Constants.Constant.LICENCE);
mGetProjectTask.params.put(Constants.Key.LANGUAGE, currentLanguage);
mGetProjectTask.params.put(Constants.Key.CTY_NAME, Constants.Value.APP_CTY_NAME);
mGetProjectTask.execute();
```

**UPDATE**
It seems that I needed to use the latest version of one of the SDKs I am using to avoid this error (Aviary SDK). When I upgraded, this error did not appear anymore.

Comment: Please post *the entire stack trace*.

Comment: can you show the code snippet where this line is `SplashActivity.java:71` also `GetProjectTask` function?

Comment: The getProjectTask is called on my onCreate method. Please see the snippet above.

Comment: Don't know what `GetProjectTask` is - may be you have an obfuscator issue?!

Comment: Obfuscator? Could it by from the dexDebug? It was having the dexDebug error before and I cannot run my app on my device. Applied a fix on it and now it works. Sadly doesn't work on lower versions. But the No Class Found error is weird.

Comment: You'll have to post the code for `GetProjectTask` as it's using some class new to Lollipop. Just because your app runs on Lollipop doesn't mean it will run on older systems...

Comment: Can you post the GetProjectTask code?

Comment: @jeraldo we need the code for `GetProjectTask`,  NOT the onCreate code that calls it.

Answer (score 5):

Your class (the first anonymous class in `GetProjectTask`) extends a class that is not available on that platform.

Comment: But before setting our project's target to Android 21. The app can support versions 4.0+. It is that one library required 21 to be able to build that it makes the app only workable in 5.0. My mimimum sdk is set to 17.

Comment: If you have library that requires API 21 then you cannot use it (including its classes) on lower APIs.

Answer (score 1):

If you look carefully at the API documentation you will notice "added in API x" at the top right corner of class documentation, and similar text in each and every API method.

For example see [AnimatedVectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html) -  it was added at API level 21 (Lollipop).

Attempting to use a class that was added at API 21 on older devices will fail with the exception that you hit. That is not surprising since unfortunately the newer features are not available in older OS versions.

You can overcome this exception in several ways: using compatibility libraries, enabling new features only if the phone supports it (by checking `Build.Version.SDK_INT` or using api level specific res folder eg. `layout-v21`.

Another alternative is to set the `minSdkVersion` to 21, then your app will refuse to install on older devices (and will not be available in their Google Play stores).

See Android docs on [compatibility](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html) for more details on this subject.

Comment: Correct me if Im wrong but I have the understanding that using compatibility libraries (appcompat) solves this. Is that not always the case?

Comment: You are wrong. The appcompat isn't magic, it implements some of the features and is bundled with your app (making your APK larger). Sometimes its possible (implementing fragments, simple animations), but some new features require stronger hardware (Shadows, blur) or deeper OS changes (vector animation uses special OS "render thread").

Comment: Also note classes in AppCompat are NOT the same classes, eg. `android.app.Fragment` uses the Fragment implemented at the OS level, and `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` implements a similar logic in your apk. Even if they look identical to the programmer who uses them, since Java is strongly typed they are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me, add  on `build.gradle`:

```
 dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize = "4g"
    }
```

Compile `'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'`

Extends MultiDexApplication in application  class

Don't `@Override` the `attachBaseContext` method